# how to save asterisk autodial log

Tags: logging, asterisk, elastix

I installed elastix 2.4 .I used .call file to generate autodial call on elastix .
I used the script that generate .call file and copy theme on directory : /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
The problem is that no log saved on elastix CDR report.
How can i save report in file or elastix CDR report ?
If anybody knows any free software to generate calls and logs , it would help me .

Thanks, Laleh

Comment: I don't have 100% working example, but as far as I remember if you need a call to be saved in CDR, call should pass through some-kind default context, where some variables are set. So basically you need to find out this context and make sure that your call using call files pass through this context.

Comment: First make sure that CDRs are saved for regullar calls, then you can check my comment above. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save call file you need add into call file

Archive: yes

AND create /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing_done/

To save cdr, you need orginize your call via Local channel dialling(not started call via sip will not go cdr) and change cdr.conf to log unanswered calls.

Free software which "generate calls and logs" called autodialler. Example is vicidial.org

Comment: i did all you said and set Local channel for dialing , it works . another question is that i have 2 pri line ( which has 60 channels ) . i want to use 50 channels from all 60 channels to make auto calls .  the script that i use , create one .call file , then wait some moments ( which define in script ) , and create another .call file . by this way in a moment just one call goes out through all 60 lines. how can i manage number of outgoing calls through  creating .call files? i used script from this link : http://www.digitaloffensive.com/2010/07/simple-asterisk-auto-dialer/

Comment: You should count your channels or count in asterisk dialplan via GROUP_COUNT. Better do both. Create dialling core without ALOT of experience with asterisk is VERY dangerous idea. Use already created dialling core.